# How to search a Windows Backup Artifact

Tags: windows, windows-7, backup, windows-7-backup

Is there a means to lookup the entire set of file and folder paths for all the files that got archived into a Windows backup file? Ideally there'd be some kind of manifest file as a text file which gets generated when a Windows Backup completes. I'd like to be able to search that text file for any file names and folder paths that I'm trying to hunt down.

I'm basically trying to find something more efficient than the Restore dialog's folder browser that lets you browse through folder by folder the contents that are in a backup file from a given backup date.

[image: Windows 7 Restore Files Dialog]

---

The motivation for looking into this capability is to verify whether or not I had a certain file, which is not in a folder I thought I placed it at, and which I may have deleted at some later time because I can't locate it in any of my current folders either. If I can identify the file in my backup folder someplace I would know that that file did exist at some point and I probably mistakenly deleted it. But if I cannot find that file in my backups then I must be totally mistaken.

As a comparison, the old Windows XP tool had this after backup completes report generation option where you could save to disk the set of all paths for all files that were backed up during the just completed backup operation. You can see in the image below it would say

> The backup is complete.
>
> To see detailed information, click Report.

[image: Windows XP Backup Complete Dialog]

Answer (score 0):

Actually I just spotted this looking closer at the Restore Files dialog, there's actually a `Search` button just before the browse buttons.

[image: Search for files to restore]

You can add columns to the search results to sort by different attributes.

[image: Search for files to restore column selections]